# Cloning Azure Web App Custom Domains to Another App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App with lots of custom domains (50+).

I'm setting up a BCDR clone of the app, but when using the Azure Web App "Clone" tool, Custom domains are explicitly excluded from the cloning process.

Is there a more automated way of copying all the custom domains (as well as SSL certificates) over to another Web App (in a different region, if it matters)?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to sync the two Web Apps up periodically, as I often add new domains (it's a multi-tenant site).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [assign a custom domain to a web app using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-configure-custom-domain?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json#sample-script) and [bind a custom SSL certificate to a web app using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-configure-ssl-certificate?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json). Also, you will find the same function commands in Azure CLI.

You could find the sample code in that links.

```
# Add a custom domain name to the web app. 
Set-AzWebApp -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname `
-HostNames @($fqdn,"$webappname.azurewebsites.net")

# Upload and bind the SSL certificate to the web app.
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname -Name $fqdn `
-CertificateFilePath $pfxPath -CertificatePassword $pfxPassword -SslState SniEnabled
```

Another option is to use ARM template. You could export the template from your app service---settings, then edit some codes to meet your requirements to deploy the new web app service with custom domains. For more references, you could see [Azure Resource Manager templates for App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/samples-resource-manager-templates)